# My banner for my web design project is not on the right place

Tags: html, css

My banner is meant to be directly under the navigation bar but as of now, there is a space between it. I tried to use top for css and it doesn't move.

The css for the banner is:

```css
/*Index CSS*/

* {
  margin:0px; padding: 0px;
    }


body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

#wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(161, 193, 217);
  position: absolute;
  width: 1250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


#welcome {
    background: url(../Resources/Header/CUiZMwBXAAAQy1M.jpg);
    width: 1250px;
    height: 480px;
}


#WelcomeTo {
    
    color: white;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Bebas;
    
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#LittleChef {
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    
    font-family: Candy Shop Personal Use;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome" name="banner">
            
            <div id="WelcomeTo" name="WelcomeTo">
            <h1>WELCOME<br>TO</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div id="LittleChef" name="LittleChef">
            <h1>Little Chef</h1>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

I've had this problem for a very long time. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MCGW.jpg) to what it looks like as of now.

Comment: Neither the code nor the question is related to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because the margin of your `h1` element.

the solution is set the margin-top of `h1` to 0.

Or you can set the padding of the wrapper